# Unable to generate exam with exams2moodle when including TikZ picture

Tags: tikz, r-exams

I am trying to generate exams with `exams2moodle` on my new laptop. Everything worked (and still works) out perfectly fine on my old laptop, but in the new one (where I have exactly the same configuration, but there's obviously something missing), even when I try to run the simplest template with a TikZ figure in R/exams  `exams2moodle("automaton.Rnw")` I get the error message

> Error in magick_image_readpath(enc2native(path), density, depth,
> strip, : rsession.exe: PDFDelegateFailed `El sistema no puede
> encontrar el archivo especificado. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/809

I have checked my installation, and seen the various posts with similar problems, but haven't been able to fix it. Any idea what might be going wrong? Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: That's my session info

> R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

> Matrix products: default

> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252

> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

> other attached packages:
> [1] magick_2.4.0         mgsub_1.7.2          ICSNP_1.1-1          ICS_1.3-1            mvtnorm_1.1-1        plotrix_3.7-8
> [7] Ryacas_1.1.3         FRACTION_1.0         stringr_1.4.0        Deriv_4.0.1          ggplot2_3.3.2        plot3D_1.3
> [13] scatterplot3d_0.3-41 MASS_7.3-53          latex2exp_0.4.0      permute_0.9-5        mpoly_1.1.1          polynom_1.4-0
> [19] pracma_2.2.9         numbers_0.7-5        exams_2.3-6

> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         lattice_0.20-41    tidyr_1.1.2        assertthat_0.2.1   rprojroot_1.3-2    digest_0.6.25
> [7] gmp_0.6-0          R6_2.4.1           plyr_1.8.6         backports_1.1.10   survey_4.0         evaluate_0.14
> [13] pillar_1.4.6       rlang_0.4.7        misc3d_0.9-0       rstudioapi_0.11    Matrix_1.2-18      rmarkdown_2.3
> [19] desc_1.2.0         splines_4.0.2      partitions_1.9-22  munsell_0.5.0      tinytex_0.26       compiler_4.0.2
> [25] xfun_0.17          pkgconfig_2.0.3    htmltools_0.5.0    tcltk_4.0.2        mitools_2.4        tidyselect_1.1.0
> [31] tibble_3.0.3       crayon_1.3.4       dplyr_1.0.2        withr_2.3.0        grid_4.0.2         gtable_0.3.0
> [37] lifecycle_0.2.0    DBI_1.1.0          orthopolynom_1.0-5 magrittr_1.5       scales_1.1.1       stringi_1.5.3
> [43] testthat_2.3.2     ellipsis_0.3.1     generics_0.0.2     vctrs_0.3.4        tools_4.0.2        glue_1.4.2
> [49] purrr_0.3.4        pkgload_1.1.0      survival_3.1-12    colorspace_1.4-1   knitr_1.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Overview

Thanks for carefully researching the problem and reporting it here. As you already worked out, the problem is not in the code within R/exams directly but with `magick::image_read()` which does not work correctly in some settings. Thanks also for reporting this to Jeroen Ooms, the `magick` maintainer.

#### Bug fix in `magick`

In response to the issue you filed, Jeroen has updated with the `magick` package on GitHub with new and updated ImageMagick binaries, see: https://github.com/ropensci/magick/pull/276. Please re-install `magick` from GitHub which should resolve the problem.

#### Workaround in `exams`

A potential workaround that avoids using `magick` could be to convert the TikZ PDF output to SVG instead of PNG. In that case `pdf2svg` (and `pdfcrop`) is needed to be on the PATH (see also the comments for further details). To try it use

```
exams2html("automaton.Rnw", svg = TRUE)
```

Or with `exams2moodle()` instead of `exams2html()`. (The latter is just easier for quickly inspecting the output.)

#### Links

- Issue in the `magick` project on GitHub: https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/272.
- Similar discussion in our R/exams forum on R-Forge: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34042&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337.

Comment: 1. I have installed `pdf2svg` and added it to the path as indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403989/how-to-add-pdftosvg-to-path-in-order-to-use-writetex-in-inkscape), but it doesn't work. I get the error message
`exams2html("automaton.Rnw", svg = TRUE)
"pdf2svg" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) 
  path[1]="C:/Users/jcano/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGk7efO/file466848b5468/automaton.svg": El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado`

Comment: 2. When I call `include_tikz()` within my `.Rnw` file, I use `format = match_exams_device()`, since I often change between `pdf`and `moodle` and it worked on my old laptop. It doesn't in my new laptop

Comment: Re: 1. `pdf2svg` is currently not found on your system. Maybe you didn't add it to the PATH or the PATH environment variable wasn't re-loaded yet? Ideally, `system("pdf2svg")` should work without error and report something like: `Usage: pdf2svg <in file.pdf> <out file.svg> [<page no>]`. If you are on Windows and the `COMSPEC` environment variable is specified, then you can also try instead of `system("pdf2svg")` to say `system(paste(shQuote(Sys.getenv("COMSPEC")), "/c pdf2svg"))` which is a somewhat safer way to make the system call to `pdf2svg`.

Comment: Re: 2. The `match_exams_device()` is fine. It's just that currently the `magick` code for converting from PDF to PNG does not work in some circumstances. Apparently, an interaction with upstream changes in ImageMagick if I understand the comments in the GitHub issues correctly.

Comment: Re 1. I have added the environmental variable to the system PATH, rebooted my laptop, and still, nothing. The two commands you mention (the `CONSPEC` environmental variable is specified) produce the following output
`> system("pdf2svg")
[1] 127
> system(paste(shQuote(Sys.getenv("COMSPEC")), "/c pdf2svg"))
"pdf2svg" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
[1] 1`

Comment: Re 1. After downloading `pdf2svg`, I put the `dist-64bits` folder within `ProgramFiles`, but when I click on `pdf2svg.exe`, nothing (apparently) happens: no dialog box, no installation wizard... just a black system command window that immediately disappears... Is that the normal behaviour?

Comment: I followed the advice in the follow StackExchange post, downloaded `dist-64bits`, renamed the folder `pdf2svg`, added it to `PATH`. Then everything worked as intended for me. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403989/how-to-add-pdftosvg-to-path-in-order-to-use-writetex-in-inkscape

Comment: OK, that was my fault, my apologies... I had kept the subfolder `dist-64bits` within the path `C:\Program Files\pdf2svg` and that was obviously preventing `R/exams` from reading the files correctly. I have fixed that and now both `exams2moodle` and `exams2html` work when the option `svg` is set. However, the option `match_exams_device()` (supposed to use `png` files when calling `exams2moodle)` still does not work. Any news about progress in that regard?

Comment: The option does work! It queries the graphics format the calling `exams2xyz()` function uses and passes this on to `include_tikz()` and then `tex2image()`. With `exams2pdf()` or `exams2nops()` `"pdf"` graphics are used by default (which work). `exams2html()` or `exams2moodle()` use `"png"` by default (which fail for you). By setting `svg = TRUE` you switch to `"svg"` for all graphics in these functions (thus including `include_tikz()`) and these work for you (if `pdf2svg` is correctly installed). The only remaining problem is upstream in `magick` to support the conversion to `"png"` again.

Comment: The problem with the `magick` package should be fixed now when using the latest version from Github. Jeroen, the maintainer, pushed this fix: <https://github.com/ropensci/magick/pull/276>. If you could test whether this also fixes the problem for you, I can update the answer correspondingly so that you can accept it.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot for your (and Jeroen's) help and support.

Comment: Thanks to you for reporting the problem here and in the magick GitHub project! I have updated my answer with the magick fix. Please accept the answer so that it is flagged appropriately here on StackOverflow as well. (To do so, click the check mark below the vote counter on the left of the answer.)